# Do Cloud Functions use the same IP when sending requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So I am running an web service API on Cloud Functions with express.js. I am wondering if cloud functions use the same IP address to send requests every time.

My users are sending requests and getting responses from the CFs. Every time a user sends a request, CF sends a request to third party API to get some data. I want to be able to **limit the number of requests sent to the third party API** each minute by the CFs. The third party API has an IP limitation, so Im trying to send requests from different IPs. Do CFs use the same IP when a function is triggered? or different IP addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no guarantees about which IP address that requests from Cloud Functions may appear to come from.  You should not depend on any apparent IPs, as they may change over time as the system upgrades and scales.

Comment: is there any possible development approach to make outgoing requests from different IPs?

Comment: You have no control over this in Cloud Functions.